# remove zeros from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove all the zeros from my data frame.

```
PRICES    SALES PURCHASES MARGINAL RESIDUAL AMPDCH MW.PUMPED_B
1:     81 1391.830  2061.830     Ccgt     1918     81   140.00000
2:     81 1315.405  1985.405     Ccgt     1858     81   140.00000
3:     81 1192.031  1862.031     Ccgt     1746      0     0.00000
4:     81 1138.187  1747.216     Ccgt     1622      0     0.00000
5:     81 1138.868  1666.639     Ccgt     1534     81    49.41176
6:     81 1140.571  1628.348     Ccgt     1503      0     0.00000
```

I tried to with

```
df[ !rowSums(df[,colnames(df)[(3:ncol(df))]]==0)==ncol(df)-2, ]
```

but the zeroes are still in the data frame. Does anybody knows any suitable solution.

The expected output looks like that

```
PRICES    SALES PURCHASES MARGINAL RESIDUAL AMPDCH MW.PUMPED_B
1     81 1391.830  2061.830     Ccgt     1918     81   140.00000
2     81 1315.405  1985.405     Ccgt     1858     81   140.00000
3     81 1138.868  1666.639     Ccgt     1534     81    49.41176
```

Comment: i'm confused. what exactly do you want? do you want to remove all rows with 0 in *any* column? remove all rows with zeros in a certain column? replace zeros with another value?

Comment: Do you want to remove the rows with zeros?

Comment: I just want to remove all the rows with zero values so that finnaly I will have a new data frame without zeroes.

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: @aikod Zero values *where* is the question that bjoseph asked. In *any* column? In a specific column?

Comment: Do you have a `data.frame` or a `data.table`? Why can't you just answer the simple questions posed to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# the same basic idea using "any"
df[!apply(df[,6:7] == 0, 1, FUN = any, na.rm = TRUE),]
#   PRICES    SALES PURCHASES MARGINAL RESIDUAL AMPDCH MW.PUMPED_B
#1:     81 1391.830  2061.830     Ccgt     1918     81   140.00000
#2:     81 1315.405  1985.405     Ccgt     1858     81   140.00000
#5:     81 1138.868  1666.639     Ccgt     1534     81    49.41176
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df1[!!rowSums(df1[, 6:7, with=FALSE])]
#       PRICES    SALES PURCHASES MARGINAL RESIDUAL AMPDCH MW.PUMPED_B
#1:     81 1391.830  2061.830     Ccgt     1918     81   140.00000
#2:     81 1315.405  1985.405     Ccgt     1858     81   140.00000
#3:     81 1138.868  1666.639     Ccgt     1534     81    49.41176
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, clear solution:

```
> df[-row(df)[df == 0],]

   PRICES    SALES PURCHASES MARGINAL RESIDUAL AMPDCH MW.PUMPED_B
1:     81 1391.830  2061.830     Ccgt     1918     81   140.00000
2:     81 1315.405  1985.405     Ccgt     1858     81   140.00000
5:     81 1138.868  1666.639     Ccgt     1534     81    49.41176
```

Comment: I would probably wrap `row(df)[df == 0]` with `unique()` there, just to avoid warnings.